# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hey there i am new in this community and i want to solve this question to pass my exam :

[image]

And what i tried to solve it :

[image]

So can anyone guide me please. Have a good day

Comment: Is this an active question or on a practice exam?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! In general it's better to write what you have done using MathJax than post a picture. You can find tips about this at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: @MichaelBurr this question asked in past years and she asking similar questions always.

Comment: @ArnaudD.  thanks for guide  , i will care it ...

Comment: You were in better shape above when you had $(\lambda-a)[(\lambda-a)^2+b^2]$ because you can immediately see that $a$ is an eigenvalue and you are left with a quadratic, which is also easy to solve (the solutions will be complex).

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial of the given matrix is easily seen to be $ (x-a)^3 + b^2 (x-a) $. (You have found this polynomial, but for some reason you expanded it, making your life much harder.) Assuming that we are searching for real eigenvalues only, the only one is $ x=a $; as $(x-a)^2 + b^2 \geq 0 $ unless $ b = 0 $, and in that case we still recover $ x=a $ as an eigenvalue. In the case $ b = 0 $ the eigenspace of $ \lambda = a $ is all of $ \mathbb{R}^3 $; in the case $ b \neq 0 $, the eigenspace is spanned by $ (0, 1, 0) $. You can see this by finding the nullspace of $ A - aI $.

The complex eigenvalues are $ a \pm ib $, and since eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent, we can say that the eigenvectors are linearly independent without computing them. (These eigenvectors turn out to be ugly, so I suspect that you are not supposed to find them.)

Comment: I didnt understand your answer, can you explain a bit more please. I am finding determinant of   λ.I-A . Especially this point (You have found this polynomial, but for some reason you expanded it, making your life much harder.)

Comment: You correctly found the characteristic polynomial of the matrix, but instead of noting that it factorizes as $ (x-a)((x-a)^2 + b^2) $, you expanded it; and then couldn't find its roots. In this factorized form, it is obvious that the only real root is $ x=a $.

Comment: are you saying there is only one possible eigenvalue => x=a ?

Comment: and when i open characteristic equation of matrix , its getting more complitaced ?

Answer (score 2):

if you use row operations notice one eigenvalue is *always* $a$.

the other two are $a\pm b i $. there's an identification

$$ a+b i = \left[\begin{array}{cr}
a & b \\ b & -a 
\end{array}\right]$$

complex numbers and $2\times 2$ matrices

---

This matrix is a rotation in complex two dimensional space $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is like $\mathbb{R}^4$.  This matrix isn't real so the eigenvector isn't real.

In the complex vector space there is a preserved direction! It could be $ (a,b)$ or perhaps $(a, bi )$.

Comment: can you help for eigenvectors please ?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  & \left| A-\lambda I \right|=\,\left| \begin{matrix}
   a-\lambda  & 0 & -b  \\
   0 & a-\lambda  & 0  \\
   b & 0 & a-\lambda   \\
\end{matrix} \right|\,=(a-\lambda )\left| \begin{matrix}
   a-\lambda  & -b  \\
   b & a-\lambda   \\
\end{matrix} \right|={{(a-\lambda )}^{3}}\,+{{b}^{2}}(a-\lambda )=0\, \\ 
 & {{\lambda }_{1}}=a\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,{{\lambda }_{2}}=a-ib\,\,\,,\,\,\,\,{{\lambda }_{3}}=a+ib \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: please , can you explain how you find λ2 and  λ3 ?

Comment: $$(a-\lambda)[(a-\lambda)^2+b^2]=0$$

Comment: $$(a-\lambda)^2=-b^2\implies a-\lambda=\pm i\,b$$

Comment: very very big thanks for you .

Comment: can you help me one of eigenvectors ?

Comment: ${{v}_{1}}=(0,1,0)\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,{{v}_{2}}=(-\operatorname{i},0,1)\,\,,\,\,{{v}_3}=(\operatorname{i},0,1)\,$

Comment: i tried like that, is this wrong ? http://prntscr.com/bf4aby

Comment: how you find that vector can you explain please .